# WordPress widget not showing up

Tags: wordpress

I've followed the tutorial correctly and it still doesn't show up.  I'm trying to use the Event Geek widget for WordPress but nothing shows up.  I've used firebug and nothing is being returned, where did i go wrong?

I put this in my functions.php

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Calendar Area',
        'id'   => 'calendar-area',
        'description'   => 'This is a widgetized area.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>'
    ));
}
```

Here is my sidebar.php

```
<ul id="sidebar" >
<?php 
if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || ! dynamic_sidebar('calendar-area') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Here is where i use get_sidebar();

```
<div id="popup-right">
            <div id="popup-title">Upcoming Events</div>
            <?php

            get_sidebar();
        ?>



        </div>
```

How do i solve this, so the calendar will appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (this will show the sidebar)

```
<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar('calender-area'); ?>
```

If you add widgets from your admin panel then it will be visible on this sidebar.

Comment: i tried that and still doesn't work. I check firebug only thing being displayed is `<ul id="sidebar" ></ul>`.. no calendar

Comment: Did you add the widget you are talikin about from your admin panel's `appearance->widgets` ?

Comment: Yes i dragged and dropped the widget into the where it says "Calendar Area"

Comment: Then it should be visible there, try adding multiple widgets and check the source.

Comment: I tried your code again and the page now doesn't load.  Shall i include `||`?

Comment: No, it should work, something else is wrong, try to find out.