# Wordpress - widgets are not showing

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

i am using neve theme + elementor, and i am trying to add widgets to my footer, but nothing shows. I am going to Appearance>Widgets>then add text and images to all footer columns - 1,2,3,4 respectively and when i hit update, and refresh the site, nothing shows.

I have checked this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368104/wordpress-widget-not-showing-up) but i have not used any code in my case(only drag and drop with elementor), so the answer does not apply to me.

i have tried to disable elementor and all other plugins, but same thing, nothing shows.

if i go to appearance>Customize and select widgets this message appears:

`Widgets are independent sections of content that can be placed into widgetized areas provided by your theme (commonly called sidebars). Your theme has 5 other widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them. You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.`

[image]

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**L.E SOLUTION** : So the solution for this issue (for the beginners of wordpress like me here that could have the same dilemma) is like Daniyal said   that before adding widgets to your Header and Footer in the `Appearance > Widgets` you actually have to design the header/footer in the `Appearance > Customize`  section, by defining through drag and droping which area of the Footer for example Footer 1 is or Footer 2 or so on. Once the areas are defined the widgets added in widgets section will appear in the correct areas defined by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you create `Footer` with elementor?

If you create footer with elementor, so footer widgets not showing and you should drag and drop widget with elementor to footer to show widget

If you don't create footer with elementor, this problem is the Theme

Comment: do i have to create the footer first?I am new to wordpress and elementor, and i thought based on a tutorial that i followed that the footer/header are standard and inbuilt and you just have to add widgets to them.Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Ok, i made it work, after tinkering with it for some time.Now i understand what you meant, i will post my solution in the post above.